# find the power series representation of $(x^2)\ln(3-x)$...

Tags: calculus, power-series

How would I find the power series representation of $(x^2)\ln(3-x)$ using term by term differentiation or integration?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange mike. Some people here will require you show what work you've done or approach you've taken to solve a homework-like problem prior to helping you. If you edit your post to include this it may help move things along.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't.

Since you want the power series,
the $x^2$ only adds 2
to each exponent.

If you know that
$\ln(1-x)
=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k}
$
for
$-1 < x < 1$,
then
$\ln(3-x)
=\ln(3)+\ln(1-x/3)
=\ln(3)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k3^k}
$
so the power series is
$x^2\ln(3)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{k+2}}{k3^k}
=x^2\ln(3)-\sum_{k=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{k}}{(k-2)3^{k-2}}
$

Answer (score 0):

Start with $${1\over 3 - x} = {1\over 3}{1\over 1 - x/3}
={1\over 3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x/3)^n. $$
Now integrate termwise and massage.